# Two-way Probability Tables

Tags: probability

## Hi, I'm having trouble solving these type of probability questions. I hope anyone of you, can assist me with these problem. Thanks!

*By the way picture unable preview right away, links is the only way to see it.*

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B0YK.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Unless you help us you are likely to get votes to close and downvotes instead of help. Please edit the question to show us at least how you would begin on one of the questions and why, and where you are stuck. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(M) = \frac{\textrm{Males}}{\textrm{Total People}} = \frac{100}{145} = 0.690$$
$$P(M\wedge E) = \frac{\textrm{Elderly}\wedge\textrm{Males}}{\textrm{Total People}} = \frac{25}{145} = 0.172$$
$$P(F | \textrm{Middle-Aged}) = \frac{F\wedge\textrm{Middle-Aged}}{\textrm{Middle-Aged}} = \frac{30}{105} = 0.286$$

Some notes: $\wedge$ means and, and $|$ means given

Comment: These are correct, of course (except that you provide way too many decimal places in the answers. The data don't support that much precision). That said, I wish you'd wait to provide answers for newcomers who have not yet learned how to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

1. How many total runners are there?
2. How many male runners are there?
3. How many elderly male runners are there?
4. How many middle-aged runners are there?
5. How many middle-aged female runners are there?

As an example, let's calculate the probability of a runner being male, given that they're middle-aged. There are $105$ middle-aged runners, and $75$ of them are male. Therefore, the probability is $75/105$.

Hope this helps.